# Parallel iteration with for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist

I have 3 lists with the same size, I tried to loop through those loop by for command, but I always get the following error, my question is how to make Parallel iteration within for loop

```
a=list[...]
b=list[...]
c=list[...]
arrayList=[a,b,c]

for x,y,z in a,b,c:
   do somthing
```

or

```
for x,y,z in arrayList:
   do somthing
```

error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use zip(), that creates tuples of same index elements from given collections:

```
>>> xs = [1,2,3,4]
>>> ys= [5,6,7,8]
>>> zs = [9,10,11,12]
>>> for x, y, z in zip(xs,ys,zs):
...     print(x,y,z)
```

the output here is:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
>>>
```